# How to update state on time with react-hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to move elements from one array to another (columnsOut to columnsIn), but at the end not all values has been transferred (usually 2 out of 5 elements), so it seems something related to asynchronous state from react and I still do not how to cope with that. Can anyone give me directions?

```
  columnsOut: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
  columnsIn: []


  function handleRemoveAllFilters(event) {
    columnsOut.forEach((col) => (
      setColumnsIn(columnsIn.concat(col))
    ));
    setColumnsOut([]);
  }
```

After running function:

```
  columnsOut: []
  columnsIn: [4, 5]
```

Comment: Can you elaborate more on how you are trying to do and what result are you expecting ?

Comment: @innocent please check the code above. As I said I need to transfer all elements from one array to another, so this is what I expect. And it should happen when I call the function handleRemoveAllFilters.

Comment: You do not need to loop through `columnsOut`. Please try: `setColumnsIn([...columnsOut]);` and share feedback. If you may have any elements previously present in `columnsIn` & you need to keep them, then try: `setColumnsIn(prev => ([...prev, ...columnsOut]));`

Comment: @jsN00b you're right, it worked! Put it as an answer than I accept as solved. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer given by @Marian [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71309609/13658816) has also been edited to match something similar to below:

```
function handleRemoveAllFilters(event) {
  setColumnsIn(prev => ([...prev, ...columnsOut]));
// above will retain existing elements in columnsIn array
// below will discard 
// setColumnsIn([...columnsOut]);
  setColumnsOut([]);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Change from setting the value for the `setColumnsIn` to getting a callback that receives the `previousState` as argument.

```
function handleRemoveAllFilters(event) {
    columnsOut.forEach((col) => (
      setColumnsIn((prevColumnsIn) => [...prevColumnsIn, col])
    ));
    setColumnsOut([]);
}
```

Comment: May I please learn if there is a reason to loop through `columnsOut` - if all you need to do is essentially `push` every element from `columnsOut` array into `columnsIn` array?

Comment: There is no reason in doing that, I imagined this function might be later extended or the op wanted it in that way. Spreading the array is more logical for all reasons, but not doing it might help op to understand the async behaviour of `setState`.